# Responsive Diamond Grid

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer um diamond grid mas eles não pegam por algum motivo, antes estava um erro e agora não tem mais o erro e mesmo assim não funciona

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
}
.diamond-grid{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    
}
.item{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.diamonds.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diamonds.css" />
</head>


<body>
  <div class="diamond-grid"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/calopsita.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <script>
    $("#diamond-grid").diamonds({
      size: 200, // Size of diamonds in pixels. Both width and height. 
      gap: 5, // Pixels between each square.
      hideIncompleteRow: false, // Hide last row if there are not enough items to fill it completely.
      autoRedraw: true, // Auto redraw diamonds when it detects resizing.
      itemSelector: ".item" // the css selector to use to select diamonds-items.
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples Lincoln, no seu código **JS** você está chamando o diamond grid em um elemento com **id** igual `diamond-grid` mas no seu **HTML** você não tem nenhum elemento com id e sim uma classe `diamond-grid`, então troque isto:

```
$("#diamond-grid").diamonds({...    // aqui está chamando por um id
```

Por isto:

```
$(".diamond-grid").diamonds({...    // aqui chamará por classe
```

> **Para mais esclarecimentos sobre como usar cada um destes seletores pode ver estes links:**

- [id](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/#id1)
- [classe](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/#class1)

Comment: muitoo obrigado, você manja de jquery ?usei o codigo de um cara que o menu é de uma cor quando está no topo e quando o scroll da pagina desce, o menu fica preto, mas assim que ele ficar preto quero que a img que no caso é a logo, troque o src que está "logooficial.png" para "logooficial2.png" tem como me ajudar se souber ? obrigado =)

Comment: Faz outra pergunta, aqui não tem como responder esta. Se esta resposta aqui lhe serviu aceite-a como resposta para que esta pergunta possa ficar como resolvida no site.

Comment: @lincolnferreira Se a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas. E se tiver outras dúvidas abra quantas perguntas precisar :)